# Formatting a string timestamp with Android

Tags: android

For some reason this has me tearing my hair out.

I have a UNIX timestamp as a string in Android.  All I want to do is format this so that it returns the date/time in the user's droid time zone.

I can convert it to a timestamp just fine, but it uses GMT rather than their localised zone.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the Calendar and Date Java classes, they contain the tools to localize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor with the `Locale` you need:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    Date dt = sdf.parse("2011-03-01 17:55:15"); 
    c.setTime(dt);
    System.out.println( c.getTimeInMillis());   
    System.out.println(dt.toString());   
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.err.println("There's an error in the Date!");
}
```

outputs:

```
1299002115000
Tue Mar 01 12:55:15 EST 2011
```